# How to get 2D histogram map of an image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

To be more specific, here is the exact requirement. I'm not sure how to word the question.
I have an image, of size say `(500,500)`. I extract only r and g channels

```
r = image[:, :, 0]
g = image[:, :, 1]
```

Then, I compute the 2D histogram of r and g

```
hist2d = np.histogram2d(r, g, bins=256, range=[(255,255),(255,255)])
```

Now, `hist2d[0].shape` is `(256, 256)` since It corresponds to every pair of 256x256 colors. Fine

The main requirement is, in an separate image, called `result` with same shape as original image i.e. `(500, 500)`, I want to populate each element of `result` with the value of 2d histogram of `r` and `g` channels

For example, if `r[200,200]` is 23 and `g[200, 200]` is 26, I want to place `result[200, 200] = hist2d[0][23, 26]`

The naive method for doing this is, simple python loop.

```
for i in range(r.shape[0]):
    for j in range(r.shape[1]):
        result[i, j] = hist2d[0][r[i, j], g[i, j]]
```

But for a large image, this takes a significant time to compute. Is there a numpy way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `hist2d[0][r, g]`:

```
import numpy as np

r, g, b = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(3, 500, 500)).astype(np.uint8)
hist2d = np.histogram2d(r.ravel(), g.ravel(), bins=256, range=[[0, 256], [0, 256]])
hist2d[0][r, g]
```

Comment: Excellent. Works. Thanks